Deploying Azure Databrick with your own datalake storage
Deploying Azure Databricks creates an additional resource group in the background, which includes a data lake. Is it possible to use the data lake that I have already deployed in Azure instead of the one provisioned by Azure Databricks?

have you tried any approach and facing blockers?

I didn't find any option of storage while deploying it, and even if I plan to use the datalake deployed by Databrick then I don't have any access to control it.

You don't have access to managed resource group created. only you can access in databricks workspace through dbfs root. if you want your datalake you can mount it to databricks

is it possible for my other application(not on Azure) to access the databrick storage?

like what applications and what data need to access from databricks storage?

for example, suppose, I am streaming the data and storing it in the dbfs storage,
and then one of my BI application which is running on-premises want to read the old data that is stored on the dbfs, in that case, is there a way that I can make my application connect to read and write the data in dbfs.

I agree with @jayshankar. You don't have direct access to the managed resource group; you can only access it through the DBFS root in the Databricks workspace. If you want to use your Data Lake, you can mount it to Databricks.
You can mount ADLS Gen2 Storage in Databricks using the approaches below:
There are two ways you can mount and use ADLS Gen2 Storage in Databricks.
The code snippet below mounts container "folder02" with Azure Databricks:
storageAccountName = "dilipstg"
storageAccountAccessKey = "xxxxxxxxx"
blobContainerName = "folder02"
mountPoint = "/mnt/01/"
if not any(mount.mountPoint == mountPoint for mount in dbutils.fs.mounts()):
  try:
    dbutils.fs.mount(
      source = "wasbs://{}@{}.blob.core.windows.net".format(blobContainerName, storageAccountName),
      mount_point = mountPoint,
      #extra_configs = {'fs.azure.account.key.' + storageAccountName + '.blob.core.windows.net': storageAccountAccessKey}
      extra_configs = {'fs.azure.sas.' + blobContainerName + '.' + storageAccountName + '.blob.core.windows.net': sasToken}
    )
    print("mount succeeded!")
  except Exception as e:
    print("mount exception", e)


2nd approach:
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<ADLS GEN 2 account name>.dfs.core.windows.net","<Access key>")


You can obtain the Access Key from the Storage account. Refer to the image below:

Results:

